# Cannot Restart or Start Stopped Process in PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have PM2 running on server, handling some `Node.Js` processes. It runs well for most of the time. Sometimes I need to stop a service temporarily for various reasons.

Strangely, I cannot start a process from `stopped` status. In other words, I cannot perform `pm2 stop myproject && pm2 start myproject` or `pm2 restart myproject`. Whenever I do that, PM2 displays following message:

```
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [myproject](ids: [ xx ])
[PM2][ERROR] Process xx not found
```

I have done workaround by deleting the process and start it all over again.

```
pm2 delete myproject && pm2 start app.config.js
```

It worked but I don't think it is a good approach. Especially when I need to stop service several times for testing purpose.

This is the `app.config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'myproject',
      script: './build/server.js',
      instances: 1,
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      autorestart: true,
      watch: ['server.js', 'app.config.js', 'src'],
      watch_delay: 1000,
      ignore_watch: ['node_modules', 'logs'],
      exp_backoff_restart_delay: 2000,
      max_memory_restart: '100M',
      log_file: './logs/app.log',
      log_date_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
      combine_logs: true,
      env: {
        SOME_ENV: 'some_value'
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. Any feedback is highly appreciated.

**[Edit]** Additional information:

- I run command as non-root user
- Interestingly, internal PM2 logs shows following item after I restart a process `PM2 error: [RestartProcessId] PM2 is being killed, stopping restart procedure...`
- `pm2 status` shows `stopped` after I run `pm2 restart myproject`. It has no id visible, but I can check it using `pm2 show myproject`

```
│ id │ name      │ mode    │ ↺ │ status   │ cpu │ memory │ 
│    │ myproject │ cluster │ 0  │ stopped │ 0%   │ 64.1mb │
```

Comment: What does the `pm2 status` command show after you start the app? Also, are you starting the app as a root or a normal user?

Comment: Have you checked the pm2 logs? It seems when you delete the pm2 processes it works fine and from the logs I can see `id` passed to the process is `xx`. It seems when you stop the process, it is not stopping properly. I highly recommend check logs and `pm2 list`

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I have edited the question. I ran the command as non-root, and the status is still `stopped`.

Comment: @yogski and what does the `App name` and `id` columns contain after `pm2 status`? Please make sure you are using the correct app name/id when running `pm2 restart` command. Also, maybe try updating `pm2` to the latest version?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek This is the result of `pm2 list` or `pm2 status`
It displays no `id` on the table, but I can check it with `pm2 show myproject`

│ id │ name               │ mode     │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ memory   │
│    │ myproject        │ cluster │ 0    │ stopped │ 0%       │ 64.1mb   │

and I'm running PM2 version 4.5.1

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara There is nothing in the `myproject` logs, but I found interesting thing in internal pm2 logs : `PM2 error: [RestartProcessId] PM2 is being killed, stopping restart procedure...`

Comment: That why I asked you to check the logs because if PM2 service is running, it automatically picks the processId in your case it is `xx` which means the service itself is stopped.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Thanks for pointing me to right direction. I am non-root user and this has to do with PM2 setting unknown by me, so this issue can be escalated internally.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the system variables have been overwritten or deleted to map the pm2 functions. I faced a similar issue when I installed **pdftk** on my system and overwrote the system variable by mistake.

Add this as your path variable

```
%SystemRoot%/System32/Wbem
```

This worked for me.